# Permission problems after migrating from Plone 4.0.1 to 4.2.5

Tags: plone

I'm migrating a site from Plone 4.0.1 to Plone 4.2.5 as follows:

- Create new instance in Plone 4.2.5 on new server
- Copy buildout, my sources, Data.fs and blobstorage from old server to new instance
- Update buildout.cfg, run bootstrap.py and bin/buildout
- Run Plone migration tool

This worked well except there are a handful of pages that redirect to the login page viewed by anonymous users.  These pages are all viewable by anonymous users on the old site.

I've looked at the Sharing settings for the affected pages and they look the same as
other pages that work correctly.  They're all set to inherit permissions and other
sibling pages work OK.

I've turned on `verbose-security` in my buildout.  I get the following traceback in the error log when an anonymous user tries to view one of these pages:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 115, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.BaseRequest, line 616, in traverse
  Module ZPublisher.HTTPResponse, line 756, in unauthorized
Unauthorized: You are not authorized to access this resource.
No Authorization header found.
```

How I can either get these pages to migrate properly or fix their after the migration?

Comment: You need to find out why the pages are unauthorized. Go to error_log in the ZMI and remove Unauthorized from the list of ignored exceptions. Then re-visit the page, find the resulting traceback in the error log, and add it to your question.

Comment: @Uh Clem: Could you proceed with David's instructions?

Comment: @Ida Ebkes: I did that and turned on verbose-security as well.  The resulting traceback is in the question.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't noticed 'cause it's so short :) Which is due to a known bug, that exceptions are swallowed silently allthough verbose-security is on:
https://dev.plone.org/ticket/12273

Supercoder and doc-carer Mikko provides a debugging-possibilty there, which might help.

Comment: Does https://dev.plone.org/ticket/12824 fit to your case?